# App.config always checkout when designing a form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, app-config, devexpress-windows-ui

First, the app.config have nothing different when we compare both versions.
I look this topic which can be useful: https://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=14026

But we have no connection string in our app config and our form doesn't have  SQL data connection related to it.

We have some HTTP binding and services but it occurs in any form which doesn't include those services.

The only thing I could see is that our form inherits from DevExpress xtraForm.
But I did add a form which doesn't inherit from XtraForm and app config still got check out when designing.

Note we are using : **TFS 2010 self-hosting** And **VS 2015**

Is there someone out there actually had this issue? this bring a lot of problem with TFS on our side

Thanks

**EDIT**

I think I finally got the problem.
From now it may be DevExpress WinForms that automatically checkout the file.

Or maybe VS 2015 have this behavior with third party UI library ??

Proof: [Video step to reproduce](https://youtu.be/CPPPyko7-xs)

See the dev express topic here: [DevExpress Topic](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T486667)

Comment: I have the same issue with random forms being checked out and marked as changed (with the red checkmark) when nothing is changed.

Comment: do you use devexpress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution will be in the devexpress 2.6 -> https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T486667